# Scheduled delivery in Clickatell

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, sms, scheduled-tasks, clickatell

I'm trying to set up the REST API, to send out scheduled SMS, but i'm failing to do so...
This is the data, i'm trying to send:

```
[
    [to] => Array
        (
            [0] => (My Phone Number)
        )

    [content] => Test
    [scheduledDeliveryTime] => 2017-07-30T14:07:00Z
]
```

Where the scheduledDeliveryTime is in UTC. Sending it out without the scheduledDeliveryTime attribute, works just fine.

I either need a way to be able to track down the issue, or just find out what's wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Got help from the clickatell team, so i'm posting their answer here, in case anybody else runs into this issue...

> The Platform format for scheduled delivery:
>
> Scheduled time should include local time zone (not just a 'zulu',
>   Z=UTC), like '2017-01-11T06:51:35-0700' or '2017-01-11T06:51:35+0200.